# Remote SSH test doesn't pass

Tags: bash

```
[machine1 ~]$ [ -z $(find /var/run/screen/S-abc/ -name '*ips' -type p) ] && echo 1 || echo 2
```

> 2

Now the problem:

```
[machine2 ~]$ for i in machine{1..1}; do ssh $i "echo -n $i;[ -z $(find /var/run/screen/S-abc/ -name '*ips' -type p) ] && echo ' 1' || echo ' 2'"; done;
```

> machine1 1

Why is it returning 1 and not 2 when executing as remote ssh command?

Comment: `[ -z $(something-that-returns-empty) ]` is the same as `[ -z ]`, not `[ -z "" ]`. `[ -z ]` is the same as `[ -n -z ]`, which returns true. You need `[ -z "$(something-that-returns-empty)" ]`, or to use `[[ ]]` instead of `[ ]`, to do what you want.

Comment: ...and that's in addition to the problems you get by using double quotes, causing your expansion to run before ssh is started, and thus on the local machine and not the remote one.

Answer (score 2):

Try doing this :

```
for i in machine{1..1}; do ssh $i <<'EOF'
    echo -n $i
    [[ $(find /var/run/screen/S-abc/ -name '*ips' -type p) ]] &&
        echo ' 1' || echo ' 2'
EOF
done
```

Comment: This works as a charm in my tests. If it don't returns what you expect, maybe you don't have any FIFO in /var/run/screen/S-abc dir...

Answer (score 0):

the `$(find ...)` command is run before the `ssh` command is executed.